# Stop Java from printing the Zero in my array list

Tags: java, arraylist

Hello I wrote my code and all of it works except that Zero is used as a way to exit, and I need it not to print at the end of my array list.

```
import java.util.*;


public class Question1 
{

public static void main(String[] args)
{
    Scanner keyboard = new Scanner(System.in);
    int user_input;     

    List<Integer> number_list = new ArrayList<Integer>();
    do
    {
        System.out.println("Enter an integer (0 to exit)");
         user_input = keyboard.nextInt();
         number_list.add(user_input);               
    } 
    while (user_input!=0);
    System.out.println("Got it.  You entered:");        
    for (int numbers : number_list)
    {
            System.out.println(numbers);                    
    }   
}
}
```

any help would be greatly appreciated thank you.

Comment: Put an if statement in before `number_list.add(user_input); ` to only allow `user_input` values that are not equal to `0` to be added...

Answer (score 2):

Changing

```
 do
    {
        System.out.println("Enter an integer (0 to exit)");
         user_input = keyboard.nextInt();
         number_list.add(user_input);               
    } 
    while (user_input!=0);
```

to

```
do
    {
        System.out.println("Enter an integer (0 to exit)");

         user_input = keyboard.nextInt();
         if(user_input !=0)
           number_list.add(user_input);      
    } 
    while (user_input!=0);
```

Should do the trick. This way, the only values that will be added are the nonzero ones.

Answer (score 0):

I changed your code a little bit to do what you want:

```
public class HelloWorld {
public static void main(String[] args)
{
Scanner keyboard = new Scanner(System.in);
int user_input;     

List<Integer> number_list = new ArrayList<Integer>();
do
{
    System.out.println("Enter an integer (0 to exit)");
     user_input = keyboard.nextInt();
     number_list.add(user_input);               
} 
while (user_input!=0);
if (number_list.size()  > 1) {
      System.out.println("Got it.  You entered:");        
for (int i =0; i< number_list.size() -1 ;i ++)
{
        System.out.println(number_list.get(i));                    
}   

}

}
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
do {  System.out.println("Enter an integer (0 to exit)");     
    user_input = keyboard.nextInt();
    if(user_input!=0){
     number_list.add(user_input);   }            
} 
while (user_input!=0);
```

Comment: Please provide more information: what was the mistake? How your code corrects it? Simply providing the solution won't help others with the same problem.